# "Failed to execute script" when trying to share exe

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller, seleniumwire

So I can compile my project and run the .exe perfectly fine on my PC but if I try to share it with others or run it on another PC I get "Failed to execute script WS.py" I tried installing selenium, selenium-wire, python, and pyinstaller all in an env to fix this so the project would have everything it needed installed already.

[Here is the error in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYBnQ.png)

Before this I was getting a pop up instead like this

[The pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5gHZ.png)

I am a nooby programmer so please explain like I'm five, thanks.

EDIT: I also have the exe in the spot where it is needed to run, I did not leave it in the dist folder. As stated it works on my PC but not on others when shared, I feel I am missing something simple here.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: First image is a error that would pop up and go away instantly and is not my code so I can not copy and paste it here, thus I shared a screenshot. Second photo is showing a visual example of the issue which I explained in my post via text.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: error in CMD shows that it can't find file `seleniumwire\ca.crt` and you have to add this file (and folder) to your exe using configuration file `.spec`

Comment: I made the ca.crt and ca.key and it is in the same place as the .py before using pyinstaller to convert it to an exe but I still get the same error, did I do something wrong?